# Код работает через раз. Не могу понять в чём проблема

Tags: c++

Решил сделать быструю сортировку на языке C++. Но код странно себя ведёт.

То он нормально выводит отсортированный список, то крашится, то выводит мусор. При удалении массива min и max тоже крашится.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void FillArray(int* const arr, const int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 10;
    }
}

void PrintArray(const int* const arr, const int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
}

//Быстрая сортировка
int SortArray(int* arr, const int size)
{
    if (size < 2)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        int pivot = arr[0]; //Нулевой элемет массива
        int size_min = 0; //Длина массива со значениями меньше pivot (min)
        int size_max = 0; //Длина массива со значениями больше pivot (max)
        int a = 0, b = 0; //Вспомогательные переменные для присваивания значений элементам массива min и max
        int *min = new int[size_min]; //Массив со значениями меньше или равными pivot
        int *max = new int[size_max]; //Массив со значениями больше pivot

        //Присвоение массивам min и max значения массива arr по условиям
        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] <= pivot)
            {
                size_min++;
                min[a] = arr[i];
                a++;
            }
            else if (arr[i] > pivot)
            {
                size_max++;
                max[b] = arr[i];
                b++;
            }
        }
        int j = 0; //Переменная для копирования значений, полученных через сортировку обратно в arr


        SortArray(min, size_min); //Вызов функции сортировки для min 
        for (; j < size_min; j++)
        {

            arr[j] = min[j];

        }
        //delete[] min;

        arr[j] = pivot;
        j++;

        SortArray(max, size_max); //Вызов функции сортировки для max
        for (int i = 0; j < size; j++, i++)
        {
            arr[j] = max[i];
        }
        //delete[] max;
        return 0;

    }
}


void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    int size = 6;

    int *arr = new int[size];

    FillArray(arr, size);

    PrintArray(arr, size);

    cout << endl;

    SortArray(arr, size);

    cout << endl;

    PrintArray(arr, size);

    delete[] arr;

}
```

Comment: `int *min = new int[size_min];` как Вы думаете, что здесь происходит при `size_min = 0`?

Comment: Отлаживать пробовали? На каком месте крашится?

Comment: Добавили бы вы комментарии, ибо не понятно для чего у вас тонна переменных.

Comment: `int* const arr` ? Cерьёзно? Что по вашему делает данная строка? Зачем делать так, это ж ничего не даёт, если не ухудшает, напишите, без `const`

Comment: Прочти вот:  https://habr.com/post/59558/

Comment: const не даёт изменить в указателе адрес массива на что-нибудь другое. На функции FillArray (Заполнения) и PrintArray (Вывода) можно не смотреть. Меня больше волнует функция SortArray, я не понимаю почему она так странно работает.

Comment: Также я не понимаю почему не получается удалить уже ненужные массивы min и max.

Comment: @AlexSuperStar: Вам же в первом же комментарии указали: вы создали массивы **нулевого** размера (!), а потом принялись в них что-то записывать (???). Все, разумеется, рухнуло с диким грохотом.